# recently couldn't install packages on R. it start ok and then 'No such file or directory'

Tags: r, package, installation

I have a problem installing any package in R studio threw 'install.packages' function. When I install a package, it downloaded the package as usual and then when it finished, i got location error problem.

Once I had no problem installing any package in R studio threw 'install.packages' function. For some reason, suddenly it doesn't work.
Now when I install a package, it downloaded the package as usual and then when it finished, I get error on the location of the file(sowed bellow).
I've been deleting and downloading again R, R studio and nothing changed. Not a single success for any package.

got sometimes recommendation:
1) "Error in install.packages : 'exdir' does not exist"
2) "Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding"
Couldn't install them as well.

Any ideas?
the code:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', lib = "'C:/Users/..../R/win-library/3.6/knitr/Meta/package.rds'")

install.packages('ggplot2')
```

#

## I got:

....

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library/"' is not writable
Error in install.packages : unable to install packages
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/..../R/win-library/3.6/knitr/Meta/package.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory
```

Comment: What about he messages "Rtools is required to build R packages", "'lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library/"' is not writable"? Looks like a mixture of UNIX and Windows. So what did you do to break it? Maybe try a fresh install.

Comment: I don't know how to break in. my computer works on 'Window 10 Home', never use 'UNIX'.
For half a year there was no problem so I guess some tool in the connection change the options in it.
By fresh you mean delete and install the R, R studio? because I did so.

Comment: there are a lot different errors with not finding rtools, please run `library(devtools)` and then
`find_rtools(debug = TRUE)` maybe you got a incompatible version of rtools.

Comment: Hi @mischva11, there is no 'devtools' in my R studio, nor 'rtools', only 'tools'. as a result of the reason I mentioned here, I can't install them.

Comment: i am aware of this, but the `find' command with debug=true returns sometimes more information you could have shared with use, seems like i can't help you more :/ good luck